# PHP JS allow one checkbox in group

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, checkbox

I've found various questions similar to what I'm looking to do, but my JS knowledge is almost non-existent so I'm unsure how to code this correctly. I have a few blocks of PHP looping to output my checkboxes like the two below:

```
<tr>
    <td class="first">
    P/Hol in lieu
    </td>
    <?php
    for( $x=1; $x<=14; $x++) {
        echo '<td class="checkbox checkbox'.$x.'"><input type="checkbox" name="phollieu'.$x.'" id="phollieu'.$x.'" tabindex="'.$x.'"></td>'."\n";
    }
    ?>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="first">
    Public Holiday
    </td>
    <?php
    for( $x=1; $x<=14; $x++) {
        echo '<td class="checkbox checkbox'.$x.'"><input type="checkbox" name="phol'.$x.'" id="phol'.$x.'" tabindex="'.$x.'"></td>'."\n";
    }
    ?>
</tr>
```

What I would like to do is create a JS loop that runs through each group (hence the class `checkbox'.$x.'` to make sure each column has the same identifier) and only allows one checkbox per group.

I found this code snippet in someone else's question, and when looking at the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aeeN4/) it does exactly what I want it to do, however I'm unsure how to modify the JS to loop. I would use static code but I want to reduce my code as much as possible for readability, and I know I can do it this way.

```
 $('input:checkbox').click( function() {
 //If the most recently checked box is in a different group
     if($(this).attr('name') != $(this).siblings(':checked').attr('name'))
     {
         //remove all checks apart from the group that the most recent check has been made
         $(this).siblings(':checked').attr('checked', false);
     }
 });
```

This is the layout: [Screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vfiessq5zgnzzyc/Untitled.png)

Comment: Have you considered groups of radio buttons instead?  This is how they behave without any modification or additional scripts.

Comment: If you use static code, it is bound to increase the number of lines of code...you won't be able to reduce it

Comment: @SurrealDreams If you look closely at my code you'll see why I can't use radio buttons.

Comment: @asprin Yes, hence why I would like to use a loop, so I **don't** have to use static code.

Comment: I don't see it - why can't you use radio buttons?  The one case I can see is if you need it to be possible to unselect any value from the list.

Comment: Because the PHP is looping through a row, but it's creating columns from those rows. I can't group the radio buttons together.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to make checkboxes act like radio buttons, but can't use radios because you want a vertical layout? You can probably make them have a vertical layout using CSS (don't ask me how to to it!), but the following does what you want:

```
<!-- sample table -->
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="col0">
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="col1">
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="col2">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="col0">
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="col1">
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="col2">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="col0">
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="col1">
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="col2">
</table>

<script>

// Simple function to add click listeners
function addClick() {
  var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
  for (var i=0, iLen=inputs.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    inputs[i].onclick = checkChecked;
  }
}

window.onload = addClick;

// Only allow one checked checkbox per column
function checkChecked() {
  var els = document.getElementsByName(this.name);
  for (var i=0, iLen=els.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    if (els[i] != this) els[i].checked = false;
  }  
}
</script>
```

The above is compatible with every browser in use, back to IE 6 or further.

#### Edit

BTW, if the *NodeList* interface supported iterators, then the following would be possible:

```
// Add simple each support in browsers with NodeList constructor
if (typeof NodeList != 'undefined' && NodeList.prototype && !NodeList.prototype.each) {
  NodeList.prototype.each = function(fn) {
    for (var i=0, iLen=this.length; i<iLen; i++) {
      fn(this[i], i, this);
    }
  } 
}

// Simple function to add click listeners
function addClick() {
  document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(el){
    el.onclick = checkChecked;
  });
}

window.onload = addClick;

// Only allow one checked checkbox per column
function checkChecked() {
  var tgt = this;
  document.querySelectorAll('[name=' + tgt.name + ']').each(function(el) {
    if (el != tgt) el.checked = false;
  });
}
```

I'm not suggesting you do the above (altough it works in modern browsers) as it's not robust, particularly for live NodeLists or those modified by the function, but illustrates possibilities. One feature of early libraries was support for selectors, the *querySelector* interface fixed that.

Now it's time to add an iterator to NodeList that will also be inherited by HTMLCollection… :-)

Comment: Yes, exactly. I pasted a link to a screenshot if you want to confirm you understand what I'm doing.

I'll give this code a whirl and let you know! :)

Comment: Rob, I tried the code, however all it's doing now is stopping me from unticking the boxes. :\ Suggestions?

Comment: No worries, just thought I would let you know. I wish I knew more about JS.

Comment: Is there any way to call it by class? Each column has the same class, i.e. Column 1 is column1, Column 2 is column2.

Comment: Yes, if you're using IE 8+ or other modern browsers, you can use `querySelectorAll('.className')` to get the collection.

Comment: BTW, I can't access the screen capture, against site policy. Best to post stuff here.

Comment: I'm fairly certain most people would be using them. And I don't have enough rep to post an image.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple jQuery function that will do what you need:

```
function theCheckboxGroups(namePrefix){
    $("input:checkbox[name^='"+namePrefix+"']").click(function() {
        if($(this).attr('name') != $(this).siblings("[name^='"+namePrefix+"']").attr('name'))
        {
            $(this).siblings("[name^='"+namePrefix+"']").attr('checked', false);
        }
    });
}
theCheckboxGroups("phollieu");
theCheckboxGroups("phoy");
```

*The last two lines call the function.*

**CAVEAT:** you will have to rename one of your 'groups', preferably the second one; because they both use 'phol' as a prefix, and so match all your checkbox elements on the page.

---

**EDIT:** I misunderstood your question. Please check the updated code below.

```
function theCheckboxGroups(namePrefix){
    $("."+namePrefix).click(function(){
        var theID = $(this).attr('class').match(/(\d*$)/)[1];
        // Add REGEX to ensure that number is preceded by letters (I'll leave that to you!)
        $("input[name$='"+theID+"']").not($(this).children()).attr('checked', false);
    });
}
$(".checkbox").each(function(){
    theCheckboxGroups($(this).attr('class').split(' ')[1]);
});
```

It is largely untested, but worked! Also, please make note of the comment in the code (see my comment about the REGEX below).

http://jsfiddle.net/9M9ez/

Comment: Is this per row, or per column?

Comment: The REGEX you will have to add will prevent cases such as the changing of four elements with names ending with, say `1`, for example... even `checkbox11`s will be included!